# RMI port 8083 already in use

Tags: windows-server-2008, jboss5.x

We are using JBoss Server 5 and trying to deploy our application. But whenever we start server, it says "RMI port 8083 is already in use". We have changed port no in binding_service.xml but whatever port we use it says port is already in use. We have window server 2008. One more thing if we use other server like tomcat it works on 8083 port on same machine, but JBoss is not. What is the problem? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

SO finally We searched on google and found some hints regarding this port issue.

[Boss issue with binding to a specific port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439452/jboss-issue-with-binding-to-a-specific-port)

Chander Shivdasani mentioned some issues that can trigger this problem. In our case the first one was the problem. We removed -b and it worked.